# why I'm getting undefined object and How do I parse json data with NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

My architecture is as follow:

- The server side is NodeJs
- The client side is HTML & JavaScript & JSON

I'm trying to send some data from client to server, but the server always get invalid data.

Server:

```
app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {   
   console.log("Got POST (RES): " + res);
   console.log("Got POST (RES-BODT): " + res.body);
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "MyWeb.html" );
})
```

Client:

```
function onSubmit() {

    var xmlhttp;
    var result = '{"Q1":1,"Q2":3,"Q3":9}'                   
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","~/process_post",true);
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(result));

    // same result when sending the next data:
    //xmlhttp.send("XYZ");
    return true;
}
```

but at the server side I'm always getting:

```
Got POST (RES): [object Object]
Got POST (RES-BODT): undefined
```

1. What am I missing ?
2. How can I get the parsed json data (Q1, Q2, Q3) at the server side ?

Thanks

Comment: You're `stringify()`ing a string, not an object.

Comment: Do you have body parser middleware installed?

Answer (score 0):

Use express body-parser, if you use express: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Add limit 50mb - for sending more date:

`app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));`

Comment: same results.
Am I sending the data in the right way ? xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(result));
How do I parse it ?